# Correct/Concisest way to nest routers with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

I can set up two routes like this

*index.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
const PORT = 3001;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello app');
});

app.use('/routes', require('./routes'));

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('listening on port:', PORT);
});
```

*./routes/index.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/sub1', require('./sub1'));
router.use('/sub2', require('./sub2'));

module.exports = router;
```

*./routes/sub1.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var subOneRouter = express.Router();

subOneRouter.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({route: 'sub1-base'});
});

subOneRouter.get('/:id', function(req, res){
    res.json({'route': 'sub1-base', 'id': req.params.id});
});

module.exports = subOneRouter;
```

For brevity *./routes/sub2.js* looks exactly the same, but its variables are named *subTwo*

What is the shortest way to nest sub2 under sub1? Within *index.js* I have tried

```
var subOne = router.use('/sub1', require('./sub1'));
subOne.use('/sub2', require('./sub2'));
```

But that didn't work at all. Within *index.js*

```
router.use('/sub1/:id/sub2', require('./sub2'));
//localhost:3000/sub1/123/sub2/456 => { "route": "sub2-base","id":"456"}
```

Does work, but it seems it could get verbose and difficult to maintain if the structure got much longer. What's the best way to do this? Is there a shorter way to nest these?

Comment: Your URL should be localhost:3000/routes/... and in your sub1.js you should define a route like this `subOneRouter.get('/:id/sub2', require('./sub2.js');` and the URL would be localhost:3000/routes/sub1/123/sub2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code in index.js makes it difficult to understand what you want. So far I understand you want a route like `/sub1/:id/sub2` but more easy to write and maintain and inside index.js.

So yes you can do it and it is quite simple.
You just need to `require` `sub1` and `sub2` and `use` `sub2` in `sub1`, then you can mount `sub1` on the router.
Ex:

```
var sub1= require('./sub1');
var sub2 = require('./sub2');
sub1.use(sub2);
router.use('/sub1:id', sub1);
```

So your index.js becomes,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
const PORT = 3001;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello app');
});

var sub1= require('./sub1');
var sub2 = require('./sub2');
sub1.use(sub2);

router.use('/sub1:id', sub1);

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('listening on port:', PORT);
});
```

This wouldn't be very difficult to maintain. Let me know if this isn't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

So you have

```
/routes/sub1  
/routes/sub1/:id  
/routes/sub2  
/routes/sub2/:id
```

if i understand correctly, you want these routes:

```
/routes/sub1/sub2
/routes/sub1/sub2/:id
/routes/sub1/:id/sub2
/routes/sub1/:id/sub2/:id
```

So your solution can be something similar to this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
    routerA = express.Router(),  
    routerB = require('./sub2');

routerA.get('/', function(req, res) { console.log('sub1 base') });

//The next 2 mounts order matters, cause they can overlap each other
routerA.use('/sub2', routerB); //routes/sub1/sub2 + routes/sub1/sub2/:id
routerA.get('/:id', function(req, res) { console.log('sub1 id:' + req.params.id) });

routerA.use('/:id/sub2', routerB); //routes/sub1/:id/sub2 + routes/sub1/:id/sub2/:id

app.use('/routes', routerA);
app.listen(3000);
```

It is up to you to decide that will there be a sub1-id called 'sub2'
Cause any request to the resource with id 'sub2' will be taken a way by routerB

Answer (score -1):

The way I would recommend to write your node.js routes would be to have a routes.js file, which will contain all your routes.

You can then put, in your routes.js file your route for sub1, like so:

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const sub1 = require('./sub1');
router.use('/sub1', sub1);

module.exports = router;
```

I would then, in sub1.js, put your sub2 route, like so:

```
const subOneRouter = require('express').Router();

subOneRouter.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({route: 'sub1-base'});
});

subOneRouter.get('/:id', function(req, res){
    res.json({'route': 'sub1-base', 'id': req.params.id});
});

const sub2 = require('./sub2');
subOneRouter.use('/:id/sub2);

module.exports = subOneRouter;
```

This will make all your sub1 routes have the prefix of '/sub1' and all your sub2 prefixes, inside sub1, have a prefix of '/:id/sub2'. You can then feel free to put whatever routes inside sub2 that you wish.

Using this setup means that if you ever want to change the prefix for sub1, or sub2, you just change it in one place.